# How do I update another MVC page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have two MVC's called "Remote" and "TV" which are running on seperate devices/browser sessions. 
I want to use the View "Remote" to update the current list of models the View "TV" (while keeping the old/current models of view TV (since I want to scroll forward and backwards). How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very vague you need to add more details, but I will try to answer it.

The view Remote and TV should be hooked up to a database. Doing stuff on the Remote view will end up updating the database. And since the TV view is looking at the same database/table, it will show the current requested channel.

The only problem is the moment remote updates the table how does the TV view know that database table has been updated. For this you can use Microsoft's cross-browser implementation of websockets called "SignalR" which will make the real time communication between the TV and Remote possible.